# HtmlUnit need thread sleep 'before' clicking button?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, htmlunit

I am trying to use HtmlUnit to scrape scores off the BBC Sports website http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/live-scores

The page loads on Premier League, then there is a dropdown to select other leagues and then click the 'Update' button to update the page (presumably via ajax).

This code works fine to get the updated scores:

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String titleBar = getTitleBar(page);
    HtmlOption option = ukGroupDropdown.getOptionByValue(competition);
    ukGroupDropdown.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);
    HtmlButton updateButton = (HtmlButton)page.getElementById("filter-nav-submit");
    Thread.sleep(1000);    // WHY???????
    HtmlPage newPage = updateButton.click();
    while(titleBar.equals(getTitleBar(newPage))) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

    System.out.println("Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    return getMatches(newPage);
```

But if I take out the Thread.sleep 'before' clicking on the update button, the 'newPage' is never updated. Why could this be? And is there a more robust way (like the titleBar loop that just gets the text from the title bar eg "Barclays Premier League" etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the line:

```
ukGroupDropdown.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);
```

Is performing an asynchronous (AJAX) call and the

```
updateButton.click();
```

line needs to wait for the former to finish.

For example, the button could be disabled but when selecting an item it might get enabled.

Comment: I think you are right, clicking on a dropdown option does seem to be an asynchronous call, since if there is a value in the other dropdown that one gets reset. However, the 'update' button is not disabled to the naked eye, and if I check updateButton.isDisabled() before the thread sleep it is not disabled. If there are no visible changes to the page from clicking the dropdown, how can I check to see if the script is finished yet?

Comment: Well, I said `disable` just to give an example but it could have been just an action that handles the JS of the `onchange` event (which is most likely). The only way to solve that would be taking a look at exactly what change the selection of the element performs in the DOM and try to query for the DOM for that update. It could be, for example, adding a new CSS class to the button or maybe setting an HTML5 attribute

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go - if I extract the html source before and after, would the change show up there? Thanks for the help, accepting your answer!

Comment: It should as long as you use the `asXml()` method. If you use the `getContentAsString()` then it won't.